# How to shutdown Linux at specific datetime from terminal?

Tags: linux, shutdown, scheduling

It seems I can shutdown using `sudo shutdown` by specifying a time or minutes.

Is there a way to specify datetime for shutdown?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can do this directly from the `shutdown command`, see `man shutdown`:

```
SYNOPSIS
   /sbin/shutdown [-akrhPHfFnc] [-t sec] time [warning message]

[...]

   time   When to shutdown.
```

So, for example:

```
shutdown -h 21:45
```

That will run `shutdown -h` at 21:45.

---

For commands that don't offer this functionality, you can try one of:

#### A. Using at

The [`at`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_at.htm) daemon is designed for precisely this. Depending on your OS, you may need to install it. On Debian based systems, this can be done with:

```
sudo apt-get install at
```

There are three ways of giving a command to `at`:

1. Pipe it:

   ```
   $ echo "ls > a.txt" | at now + 1 min
   warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
   job 3 at Thu Apr  4 20:16:00 2013
   ```
2. Save the command you want to run in a text file, and then pass that file to `at`:

   ```
   $ echo "ls > a.txt" > cmd.txt
   $ at now + 1 min < cmd.txt
   warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
   job 3 at Thu Apr  4 20:16:00 2013
   ```
3. You can also pass `at` commands from STDIN:

   ```
   $ at now + 1 min
   warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
   at> ls
   ```

   Then, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to exit the `at` shell. The `ls` command will be run in one minute.

You can give very precise times in the format of `[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss]`, as in

```
$ at -t 201403142134.12 < script.sh
```

This will run the script `script.sh` at 21:34 and 12 seconds on the 14th of March 2014.

#### B. Using cron (though this not a good idea for shutdown)

The other approach is using the `cron` scheduler which is designed to perform tasks at specific times. It is usually used for tasks that will be repeated but you can also give a specific time. Each user has their own "crontabs" which control what jobs are executed and when. The general format of a crontab is:

```
*     *     *     *     *  command to be executed
-     -     -     -     -
|     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |     +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

So, for example, this will run `ls` every day at 14:04:

```
04 14 * * * ls
```

To set up a cronjob for a specific date:

1. Create a new crontab by running `crontab -e`. This will bring up a window of your favorite text editor.
2. Add this line to the file that just opened. This particular example will run at 14:34 on the 15th of March 2014 if that day is a Friday (so, OK, it might run more than once):

   ```
   34 14 15 5  /path/to/command
   ```
3. Save the file and exit the editor.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5473841/1081936) SO answer suggests a way to have it run only once but I have never used it so I can't vouch for it.

Comment: Scheduling a shutdown with cron is a really bad habit. Suddenly you will wonder why the server is down every Monday morning.

Comment: @Ouki Which is why I did not even use it as an example, if you read carefully, I gave the way to do it for `shutdown` and then moved to other programs. Also, you're assuming the OP is using a server which is probably not the case.

Comment: @Ouki I-m sorry but I just don't see where I recommend using cron for shutdown. I mention in a parenthesis that it is possible (it is) but do not recommend it. We tend to like comprehensive answers here which is why I offered the other alternatives while never suggesting they should be used for `shutdown`.  I feel for that bad experience though, that couldn't have been pleasant.

Comment: This is more about suggestion, as you are mixing `shutdown` scheduling and `cron` in the same answer... Whether it is a workstation or a 1000 users mail server (my sad experience) is more about the consequences of a bad habit.

Comment: I'm with Ouki here. When discussing `shutdown`, one should not include `cron`. (esp. with someone who won't know why that's a horrible idea.)

Comment: Is it really possible to have a unix system where `at` is not yet installed?

Comment: @gerrit "User-friendly" distributions like Ubuntu don't install it by default. Debian does, but not Ubuntu so, presumably, not any of the Ubuntu derivatives either.

Comment: This is the linux/unix answer. It is unfortunate that the "install this gtk application" was chosen.

Comment: I'm a little confused that this answer seems to lead with information already assumed by the question. It looks like the OP knows how to specify a time for shutdown, but wants to know how to specify both a date and a time. That is addressed in this answer, but it's provided as if it's extra information, when it's what was being asked for in the first place.

Comment: @RickyBeam (and OP, i.e. terdon), why is using cron for shutdown horrible idea?

Comment: @Ouki, I would like your inputs about why is using cron for shutdown bad idea as well. Is there anything else except the possibility one could forget about it?

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić please don't start that sort of discussion in comments. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465337/5132 for some of the differences and similarities between giving the time to `shutdown` and giving the time to `at`.

Answer (score 31):

No, you can't specify a date at the shutdown command, but two alternatives exist:

1. The easiest is to use [the at command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at). 
   The following example will execute `shutdown +5` at a specific time and day:

   ```
   echo "shutdown +5" | at 10:05am 2019-01-19
   ```
2. If you do not mind using your calculator
   and want to shutdown in, say, 24 hours (24×60=1440 minutes)
   and you are absolutely sure the system will not reboot in between:

   ```
   shutdown +1440
   ```

Comment: The reason for my answer above: terdon's answer is correct and very comprehensive but too chatty (IMHO at least)

Comment: If by chatty you mean helpful and comprehensive... Your answer didn't even explain the `at` command .

Comment: @Anthony I believe this way of using `at` deserves no explanation. I can see you believe otherwise. Different minds, different views.

Comment: This answer is no longer true.  The van Smoorenburg, Upstart, and systemd `shutdown` commands do not allow a date specification.  But the nosh toolset's `shutdown` does, supporting the long-standing BSD syntax.

Comment: @JdeBP: what alternative of the two do you believe is no longer true and have you tested and verified they are not? I've just tested both commands in 3 systems (Ubuntu 18.04,16.04 & CentOS 7) and they worked fine. Regarding the rest of your comment ("The van Smoorenburg...") I'm not sure if it's a clarification of your statement that this answer is no longer true or a general comment. Maybe you should post an answer with a bit more information.

Comment: The bit that is no longer true is the bit that I _explicitly contradicted_.

Comment: Sorry JdeBP but your explicit contradiction is not clear *to me* and these commands still work on the platforms that I've tested them. Either me or you are misunderstanding the other. Really sincere question: Have you done any testing and found that my commands fail and if yes which command and on what platform(s)?

Comment: Please read _the first ten words_ of your answer.

Comment: :-D yes, I was concentrating on the alternatives and you on the shutdown command options. Do you know if this nosh toolset is popular on some subset of the *nix world. I didn't know about it but I'm only regularly in contact with Ubuntu/Debian/CentOS.

Answer (score 8):

It will shutdown your system at 12:00 :

```
$ sudo shutdown -h 12:00
```

**Options:**

```
-h, -P, --poweroff
```

Power-off the machine.

```
-r, --reboot
```

Reboot the machine.

```
-c
```

Cancel a pending shutdown.

Comment: Your method not showing how to shutdown on a specific date...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it (change `DATE` as you need it):

```
DATE="2022-11-19 13:18" && crontab -l | { cat; echo "${DATE:14:2} ${DATE:11:2} ${DATE:8:2} ${DATE:5:2} * [[ \$(date +\%Y) -eq ${DATE:0:4} ]] && $(which shutdown) now"; } | crontab -
```

This adds a new entry to the crontab, which can be checked as follows:

```
crontab -l | grep shutdown
18 13 19 11 * [[ $(date +\%Y) -eq 2022 ]] && /sbin/shutdown now
```

`18 13 19 11` means that it gets executed at the [19th of november every year at 13:18](https://crontab.guru/#18_13_19_11_*), but as the crontab contains a condition, it is only executed in the year `2022`.

Delete all scheduled shutdown entries:

```
crontab -l | sed -E '/.*&&.*shutdown/d' | sed '${/^$/d}' | crontab -
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to shutdown you machine immediately you can type in terminal

`$ shutdown -P -h now`

With that "now" argument. Computer don't don't halt anyway.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I think you may have misinterpreted the OP's intention to specify an "absolute" date in the future at which the computer is to shut down.