# How can I shutdown a RHEL server at 06:45 tomorrow morning?

Tags: command-line, rhel, date, shutdown

I just received notification that our site has a power outage tomorrow morning.

I am a Windows admin but I have to cover for our Linux admin who's not around until tomorrow evening.

I need to shutdown our RHEL server at 06:45 tomorrow morning (without me doing it).

I have searched on here but see mixed answers using `shutdown`, some say `-h`, some say `-p`, some say something completely different.

**It's ~21:15 now and I need to shutdown at 06:45 in the morning. What is the simplest way I can schedule this?**

Comment: shutdown command have an option to start in futur. use `man shutdown` on your system.

Comment: I think there may have been more attempts search as this question is found in many forums, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120506/how-to-shutdown-linux-at-a-specific-datetime-from-terminal/120509#120509

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `shutdown`:

```
sudo shutdown -h  06:45 &
```

And to check it:

```
ps -aux | grep shutdown
```

If you want to cancel it:

```
sudo shutdown -c
```

This assumes of course that the shutdown time has already passed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I do this it just hangs until I Ctrl+C it ... `]# shutdown -g 06:45

Shutdown cancelled.
`.

Comment: @user4166144 Updated to background the process.

Comment: Great. I have `shutdown -g 06:45` in `ps` output now. I take it I'm ok to close the SSH session, right?

Comment: If it said that it is going to shut down in XXX minutes. It should shutdown within a few seconds of that time.

Comment: What exactly is the `-g` option?  My Fedora 21 and CentOS 7 systems don't have that option.  They just need the time, as in `shutdown 06:45`.

Comment: I think its short for `graceperiod`. It will after the graceperiod run `shutdown -h time` Although it might have been deprecated. -h would work just as well. And is documented. I updated my answer.

Comment: instead of killall, why not shutdown -c ?

Comment: About closing the ssh session --- you can check (close and enter again, check if the `shutdown` is still running). Otherwise you'll need `sudo nohup shutdown...` ---although it *shouldn't* be needed (the HUP signal will be sent as a normal user, so...)

Answer (score 37):

You should use the `at` command:

```
$ sudo at 6:45
[sudo] password for root: 
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> poweroff
at> <EOT>
```

Don't type the `<EOT>`, but press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> at the second `at>` prompt.

The significant advantage of using `at` over using `shutdown` with a TIME argument, is that it involves real, persistent, scheduling, and works even if the machine is rebooted in the intermediate time period. The `shutdown TIME` will not restart automatically in such an event, which might cause a double ungraceful power off if the reboot in the intermediate time period was not anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

Another way

`su -c 'echo "systemctl poweroff" | at 06:45'`

Comment: Assumption in your comment is RHEL7.  Earlier versions would need to be done differently.