# How to schedule shutdown every day?

Tags: cron, startup, shutdown, scheduling

We have a server that is used for Linux thin clients in a class. The server is started when required and I want to schedule it to power off at 22:00 every day to avoid power wasting.

I thought of using crontab but, after reading [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120506/how-to-shutdown-linux-at-a-specific-datetime-from-terminal/120509#120509), I am not sure if it is a good idea. Is it better to include `shutdown -h 22:00 &` in a start up script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `shutdown` command has already an embedded scheduler so you don't need a cron job for it to run at the specified time.  In Linux as everywhere else, it's better to stick to the KISS principle (Keep It Short and Simple).

`shutdown -h 22:00` will work fine, no need to run it in the background.  Add the command at the end of `/etc/rc.local` (or `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` depending on your system) for execution in the last startup script.

The advantage of not using `cron` is that in this way the shutdown remains scheduled during the day, and you can cancel it at any time by typing

```
shutdown -c
```