# Why would it not be a good idea to schedule a shutdown with cron?

Tags: cron, shutdown, at

In an answer to the question [How to shutdown Linux at a specific datetime from terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120506/158988) a high-rep user provides two solutions: using `at` and using `cron`. The cron-based option says "this not a good idea for shutdown".

Why would this not be a good idea?  I know that `at` removes tasks from its queue after executing them, while jobs entered in cron just remain visible. Are there any other arguments besides the above that would support using `at` over `cron` for a shutdown?

Comment: It's all explained in the comments to that answer....

Comment: Actually xe provides _three_ solutions, the primary one being right at the start of the answer.

Comment: @xenoid Comments cannot be relied upon to be permanent.

Comment: Nor are answers...

Comment: @xenoid That's not the same thing. Comments are explicitly intended to prompt clarifying edits. Comments don't replace answers.

Answer (score 3):

`cron` is used to specify repeated tasks. Executed tasks remain visible and **active**.

If you schedule via cron a shutdown for the 14 of the month and forget to remove the cron job afterwards, the server will shut down again one month later. When working with systems it's a good habit to make things as foolproof as possible.